# Applet Overlapping

Tags: jquery, javafx

I have created an javafx applet which will be loaded in a jquery pop up. I have one more pop up which will also be loaded in the same page.

When i click the applet pop up and then click the normal pop up. I can see that the applet pop up is overlapping the pop up. Please suggest any solution.

```
<html>

<script>

    function openPopup() {
                $("#dialogID").dialog();
                getAudioPlayer("dialogID");


        }
            function openPopup1() {
                $("#rubricID").dialog();


        }
        function getAudioPlayer(parentObj) {
        alert("HI");
      var fxstring = javafxString(
        {
                archive: "JavaFXApplication1.jar",
                width: 250,
                height: 80,
                code: "javafxapplication1.Main",
                name: "myApplet",
                id: "myApp"
        }
      );
      document.getElementById(parentObj).innerHTML = fxstring;
    }



</script>
<input value="Audio Response" onclick="openPopup()" type="button">
<input value="Pop Up" onclick="openPopup1()" type="button">
    <div id="dialogID"
                style="display: none; width: 1000px; height: 1000px; overflow:visible; background-color: #AAAAAA; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans Serif; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;z-index: -1;">

        </div>

            <div id="rubricID"
                style="display: none; width: 1000px; height: 1000px; overflow:visible; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans Serif; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;z-index: 100;">

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post some of your codes :) so we can have a better look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

check on th css I think it has something to do with the zindex

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/EqUxz/ for a sample :)